# User Specific Raise Notice/Exception/hook:

Tags: database, postgresql

For a particular database user - I want that whenever he runs any dml on any of my table in database - at the time of running the dml - first database should first popup/prompt to him like : "Are you sure to update this!" - after that it should allow him to do the update. Any easier way to make it happen?

**Things I have tried already:** I tried for one table where I have created a trigger on a table with trigger function which raises the same  message on each update. However, whenever the user update into the table- it's not popping up anything.. It's simply just let him update

Comment: `raise` anything except `exception` is for debugging purpose and not for interacting with end-user.

Comment: The DBMS cannot pop up anything to the user. Keep in mind that it doesn't even necessarily run on the same machine the user works with (nor on the same OS, nor having the same permissions as the user, etc.). If you want something to pop up, you need to implement this in the client.